# Hidding a DIV after POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a `DIV` after posting variables with `window.location.assign`. The variables are posted if the `checkbox` inside the `DIV` is selected.

My code is below.

```
$(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function () {
   var db = $(this).val();
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("db", db);
   window.location.assign("index.php?db=" + db);
   document.getElementById('dbdisplay').style.display='none';
});
```

The problem I am having is that the `DIV` is only hidden temporarily before the page is refreshed via `.assign`. I have tried to use `location.href` instead but this doesn't post by `db` variable so my `PHP` code won't run. How can I fix this??

Comment: Why you are not using AJAX ?

Comment: + If you re already using jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById('..').style.display = 'none'`. Use `$('#..').hide()` instead.

Comment: You may do 1) hide the div in css 2)check for querystring 'db' being set 3)if not set, diplay the div in JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution along the same lines of what you've been trying.

CSS:

```
#dbdisplay { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
//Check if there is querystring matching db=somevalue
//and if "no", display the div
if (!location.search.match(/db=[^&#]+/i)) {
    $("#dbdisplay").show();
}

$(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function () {
   var db = $(this).val();
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("db", db);
   window.location.assign("index.php?db=" + db);
   $("#dbdisplay").hide();
});
```

Comment: I want the DIV to be displayed so that the user can select the checkbox on initial load-up.

Comment: That's what it's doing now!

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't work because the page loads without the div.

Comment: It DOES work if your initial page load is, let's say, /index.php.

Comment: By the way, I had a missing `)` in my `if`which I just corrected! And [look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/nwat4huj/1/). Though the `div` is hidden in css, it shows when the page is loaded as there is no `?db=whatever`

Comment: I should syntax check the code before trying it, thanks.